# different zoom level for same shapefile arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

I have a road Shapefile in ArcMap which includes three different type of roads highway, motorway, streets. I want to display all these roads at different scale. One way to do this is to create three new shapefiles and set zoom level for each of these but this is not what i want. I heared that ArcMap modelbuilder can do this but can't find any help.

Comment: This does not sound like a use case for ModelBuilder to me.  The duplicate that I've pointed too will enable you to do what you describe using a single dataset (shapefile, feature class).

Comment: but that is just creating copies of dataset, which i don't want to create.

Comment: Please re-read the answer, and try it - it uses the same underlying dataset filtered by applying definition queries to layers based on that ONE dataset - the dataset is NOT copied, only the layers based on it.

Comment: how can i apply scale dependency ??

Comment: Scale dependency is one of each layer's Properties on the General tab.